# How do I find documents in a collection that contain a specific expression in their fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose model (collection posts):

```js
const Post = new Schema({
    title: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    text: {type: String, required: true}
    ...
})
```

I want to find documents in this collection that contain a specific expression in the `title` or `text` fields. That is, for example, if the `title` or `text` of the document contains the expression "hello world", then we display the document. How I do this in mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) with [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) like this:

```
yourModel.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "title": {
        "$regex": "hello world"
      }
    },
    {
      "text": {
        "$regex": "hello world"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RJUUoDUKJxF)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let strRegex = /.*hello world.*/i

let res = await Post.find({
    $or: [
        {
            title: { $regex: strRegex }
        },
        {
            text: { $regex: strRegex }
        }
    ]
});
```